# Android HtmlCompat.fromHtml <del> tag is not working

Tags: android

I have this kind of price html from server

```
<del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#8377;</span>12,000.00</span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#8377;</span>3,999.00</span></ins>
```

I am using HTMLCompact to render it in textview

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(description, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
```

But discount text is not StrikeThrough. Del tag is completely being ingnored.

**Code Implementation as requested**

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/course_name"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
   android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semi_bold"
   app:renderHtmlText="@{viewModel.product.priceHtml}"
   android:textSize="18sp"  />


//Binding Adapter
@BindingAdapter("renderHtmlText")
fun bindRenderHtmlText(view: TextView, description: String?) {
    if (description != null) {
        view.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(description, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    } else {
        view.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Which API level are you running the code on?

Comment: `targetSdkVersion 30` and app running on Android Version 7.1.2

Comment: Have you tried a simple `<del>12,000.00</del>`? IOW, is your problem `<del>`, or is your problem `<del>` with two nested `<span>` tags?

Comment: @CommonsWare normally it works fine problem with nested span

Comment: You'll have to post more code. There may be an extra `toString()` or something else that removes formatting.

Comment: @EugenPechanec code posted

Answer (score 1):

Based on the logic of `handleEndTag` from Android framework [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java#844), outer `del` tag might be ignored by inner `span` tag.

The suggestion solution is add an inline style `style="text-decoration: line-through;` for compatibility like below.

```
<del>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" style="text-decoration: line-through;">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#8377;</span>12,000.00
    </span>
</del>
<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#8377;</span>3,999.00</span>
```

Or ajdust your html page structure to make `del` tag inside `span` tag.

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"><del>&#8377;</del></span><del>12,000.00</del>
</span>
<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#8377;</span>3,999.00</span>
</ins>
```

Comment: Actually this api is made by woocommrce I cannot change it from server side.

Comment: Can you change the `description` text when you do rendering?

Comment: `description.replaceFirst("<span", "<span style=\"text-decoration: line-through;\"")`

Comment: This looks right to me and looks like a bug. I will add that neither "<del></del>" nor "<span></span>" are supported prior to API 24.  (Please correct me if I am wrong about this.)  To support APIs before API 24, a more complete solution would to do the above for API 24+ and to implement an _Html.TagHandler_ for APIs below 24.

Comment: With a customized `Html.TagHandler` sounds a reasonable solution for compatibility.